# Compare TextView and EditText on eclipse

Tags: android, string, textview, compare, android-edittext

i got a problem, how to compare textview and edittext, here the code

```
public class GameApps extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView score;
TextView right;
TextView wrong;
TextView totalquestion;

TextView question;
EditText answer;

Button submit; 
Button exit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    right = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    wrong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    totalquestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);

    question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    question.setText("banana");

    answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      **question.getText().toString();
      answer.getText().toString();
    if(v==submit){

        if(question.equals(answer)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }**
    if(v==exit){
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

i have compare answer and question but it did not match, every time i compare it always say wrong answer, how to compare it, anyone can solve this problem?? i mess up with this :(

Answer (score 2):

```
if(question.getText().toString().equals(answer.getText().toString()))
  {           
      // do something       
  }           
else  {
      //do something
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                if(question.getText().toString().equals(answer.getText().toString()))
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Correct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                finish();
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the `TextView` Object to the `EditText` Object.

Instead you need to compare their *contents*.

So

```
if(question.equals(answer))
```

will be

```
String q = question.getText().toString();
String a = answer.getText().toString();
if(q.equals(a))
```